# change one table data when single column all data of another table is equal to some value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have created 2 tables named snag_list and defect_list. I need to change the status field of snag_list to 2 when all the defect_list status should to be 2

Comment: Please share your table schemas

Comment: Welcome to the site. You don't appear to have provided all the information someone would need to answer your question. Please read [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) carefully and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but try to create a trigger for defect_list
and check the distinct count of status column if it is one and the value is 2 then update the snag_list a example would look like this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER checkstatus 
    AFTER UPDATE ON defect_list
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE cnt INT 
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT status) FROM defect_list INTO cnt
    DECLARE st INT 
    SELECT DISTINCT status FROM defect_list LIMIT 1 INTO st
    IF(cnt = 1 AND st = 2)
        UPDATE snag_list SET status = 2
    ENF IF
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague but I guess this is what you may be looking for.

```
DECLARE
   count_rec VARCHAR2(10);
   data_rec VARCHAR2(10);   
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT status) INTO count_rec FROM defect_list;
   SELECT DISTINCT status INTO data_rec FROM defect_list;
   IF (count_rec = '1' AND data_rec = '2') THEN
      UPDATE snag_list SET status = '2';
   END IF;
END;
```

edit -> You can change the datatype of the 2 variables as required. Go with VARCHAR2 if you're unsure whether the data would be numeric.